# How can I get a count from a table joined to a Left Outer Join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, outer-join

I have three tables. A table of tests (AdminTest), a table of tests that belong to a user (UserTest) and a table of questions that belongs to each of the user tests (UserTestQuestion):

AdminTest

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AdminTest] (
    [AdminTestId]  INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]        NVARCHAR (100) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_AdminTest] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AdminTestId] ASC));
```

UserTest

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserTest] (
    [UserTestId]    INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [AdminTestId]   INT      NOT NULL,
    [UserId]        INT      NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_UT] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserTestId] ASC));
```

UserTestQuestion

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserTestQuestion] (
    [UserTestQuestionId]  INT              IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [UserTestId]          INT              NOT NULL,
    [Answered]            BIT              DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT [PK_UQ] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([UserTestQuestionId] ASC)
);
```

- An AdminTest may or may not have a UserTest
- A UserTest will always have UserTestQuestions

I created this SQL to get data from AdminTest and UserTest:

```
SELECT  userTest.StartedDate,
        temp.AdminTestId 
        -- AnsweredCount
        -- I want to get a count of the number of rows
        -- from the table UserTestQuestions that have
        -- the column 'Answered' set to 1 here.             
FROM
( SELECT AdminTest.AdminTestId
  FROM   AdminTest  
  JOIN   AdminTestQuestion ON  AdminTest.AdminTestId = AdminTestQuestion.AdminTestId     
GROUP BY 
  AdminTest.AdminTestId
) temp
LEFT OUTER JOIN UserTest ON  temp.AdminTestId = UserTest.AdminTestId
-- I want the above join to only join those UserTest tables that 
-- have a value of UserId set to for example 25
```

But now I am stuck and there are two things I need help with.

- I need to be able to show only the UserTests that belong to a given UserId
- I need to report a count of the rows in the UserTests that have Answered set to 1.

Can someone give me advice on how to add this functionality to my SQL?

Here's an example of what I need:

```
AdminTestId   UserTestStartedData  AnsweredCount

1             1/1/2001             25
2             2/2/2002             10
3                
4             4/4/2004             10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the `UserTestQuestion` table and use `Conditional Aggregate` to count only when `answered = 1`

```
SELECT userTest.StartedDate,
       temp.AdminTestId,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN UT.answered = 1 THEN 1
             END) cnt
FROM   (SELECT AdminTest.AdminTestId
        FROM   AdminTest
               JOIN AdminTestQuestion
                 ON AdminTest.AdminTestId = AdminTestQuestion.AdminTestId
        GROUP  BY AdminTest.AdminTestId) temp
       INNER JOIN UserTest
                    ON temp.AdminTestId = UserTest.AdminTestId
       INNER JOIN [UserTestQuestion] UT
               ON UserTest.UserTestId = UT.UserTest 
       Where  UserTest.UserTestId = 25
```

Also If you want join to only join those `UserTest` tables that 
have a value of `UserId=25` then `left join` will be converted to `Inner join`

**Update :**

```
SELECT A.StartedDate,
       temp.AdminTestId,
       Count(CASE
               WHEN A.answered = 1 THEN 1
             END) cnt
FROM   (SELECT AdminTest.AdminTestId
        FROM   AdminTest
               JOIN AdminTestQuestion
                 ON AdminTest.AdminTestId = AdminTestQuestion.AdminTestId
        GROUP  BY AdminTest.AdminTestId) temp
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT userTest.StartedDate,
                               UT.answered,
                               UserTest.AdminTestId
                        FROM   UserTest
                               INNER JOIN [UserTestQuestion] UT
                                       ON UserTest.UserTestId = UT.UserTest
                        WHERE  UserTest.UserTestId = 25) A
                    ON temp.AdminTestId = A.AdminTestId 
Group by A.StartedDate,temp.AdminTestId
```

Comment: I would like to display all the AdminTest tables and also those userTest tables that exist (have the same AdminTestId) and have a UserId = 25.  Is there a way I can leave the LEFT OUTER JOIN and also add in a WHERE to limit the UserTest tables to those with the 25 userid ?

Comment: I think I still need the LEFT OUTER JOIN as I want to show a list of the Admin tables even if there are no user tables. I just added an example of the output I need to the question. I hope it makes it a bit more clear.

Comment: I think your latest update is close to what I need but I still get an error. I took the code you gave me, ran it and I have added the code and the error message to the question so you can see what the message is. A couple of small changes I made are there (UserTest > UserTestId) near the bottom and I also set the check in the WHERE to 1 =1 so I could test it easily. Hope you have some ideas about the error message. Do you think the count of questions with Answered = 1 should be made inside the last SELECT that's 8 lines from the end of the code?

Comment: Thanks very much.  This works now!  Just one small question. I see you are doing the count of WHEN A.answered in the outermost select. Do you think it would be more efficient if this was done in the innermost select that starts with "LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT userTest.StartedDate," ?

Comment: @Alan - I hope both will have similar execution plan